# Apple Store Device Compatibility

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I've uploaded my application in Apple Store and the OS requirement is iOS9 and I've '1' for UIDeviceFamily in info.plist, which means it's only for iPhone devices (and also iPod).

In additional, I've changed UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities and I've added arm64.

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
        <array>
                <string>armv7</string>
                <string>arm64</string>
        </array>
```

But in Compatibility section in Apple Store, I have all iPad compatible with iOS 9 like: 'iPad Air, iPad Air Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad mini 2, iPad mini 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad Air 2,' etc... and in the other side, my application is not present in iPad store !

How can I remove iPad in this list? (I've coded in Xamarin.iOS and not Xamarin.Forms or Xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you choose the iPhone in the Device family of Deployment Info. It can also run on iPad, just show a scaled and centered view on the iPad screen to fit an iPhone screen size (leaving an empty space around).

Generally we should make sure that the app can run on the iPad. Otherwise your APP will not pass the review.

That is to say, iPad option will always show up in the Compatibility section on Apple Store, but it will not affect user’s usage in the APP Store.

If you do not want your APP to adapt iPad compatibility on APP Store. You can add item `telephony` under the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
 <array>
   <string>armv7</string>
   <string>arm64</string>
   <string>telephony</string>
 </array>
```

Because  some model of  iPad  have supported  “arm64”  but do not support telephony.

[image]

Comment: Ah great ! I will add this option and I'll see the result! Thanks for you answer

Comment: But if I add telephony, the iPod users will not be happy ! because I have lots of iPod users :(

Comment: Try to use healthKit . It has been supported after iPod5 . And you can assecc the link for more information
 https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html